# Historical EUR exchange rates

Tags: data-request, finance, europe

I am looking for a panel dataset of the EUR with other countries / currencies that give the average exchange rate in each year. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [finance.yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX/history?p=EURUSD%3DX)?